# How to create a custom event pattern in aws cloudwatch rule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm having **CloudWatchLogs** as the source and I'm having a lambda function to invoke the event as the target.

In the current approach, whenever a log stream get's created the lambda fires up. But what I want is, to write a custom event pattern in the *Cloudwatch rule* so that, only whenever the log message contains Exception or Error, it should fire the lambda. Is this possible?

Cos currently the event I get from **CloudwatchLogs** in lambda, does not contain any details with regards to log message. Hence how can I create a custom pattern to fire lambda only when a log contains the word **Exception** in the rule itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the filter pattern when creating the subscription: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can I set this filter pattern to all existing log groups and any log groups that gets created?

Comment: Yes, you can just create new subscription on existing log group and target lambda.

Comment: But I wanted the subscription for all the existing log groups and the ones that will be created.. is that possible? Cos as of now I see it can be only done for one log group.

Comment: The `PutSubscriptionFilter` API takes a log group name as a required parameter. You need to create a new filter for each existing log group and a new filter for any new log groups.

Comment: right..got it! just wanted to make sure that one filter cannot be used for the entire log groups. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CloudWatch Logs trigger with a filter pattern `Exception`. This will match with the following cases:

`Exception code 1`

`[Exception] An error has occured`

`ExceptionCode 223`

but not:

`EXCEPTION CODE 1`

Note that filters are case sensitive. More details on syntax is at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html

Comment: But how would you set that in the event pattern in Cloudwatch rule? Because currently the Cloudwatch Logs event has only this { "source": [ "aws.logs" ] } . When I capture this event in lambda, it does not contain any exception or log message related details.